# Is there a way to make a div act as an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mobile, scanning

This is what I currently do.
This code is on a mobile device, so whenever I select the input field, the keyboard comes up and the current place with a focus loses its focus.

```
$("#scanner").select();
$("#scanner").on("keyup", function(){
    getScannedItem($(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
    $("#scanner").select();
})
```

Is there a way to do this in lets say... a div or a p tag?

Comment: Why did I even get a -1 for this? Its a question

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [element editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Comment: This would work if it could have a permanent focus or always ready to read incoming text... but that is really useful